# Express.js, bin/www settings and Socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

PROBLEM SOLVED.

See my answer below please.

---

PROBLEM:

I'm trying to make socketio and express work on the same port and here's the error I get.

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:80
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:874:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:897:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1221:19)
    at listen (net.js:1270:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1366:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/app.js:22:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
```

I can get my server started using sudo npm start, but now I have two servers running, localhost:3000 (express) and localhost:80 (express and socket.io)

> How can I disable the :3000 one without breaking anything in the
>   bin/www?

I'm using Express 4.

Here's my view

```
html
    head
        title Socket.io
        script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")
    body
        script(src="javascripts/ol.js")
```

ol.js (client side)

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', {my: 'data'});
});
```

Here's my app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var http = require('http');
var router = express.Router();

var app = express();

var server = http.Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
server.listen(80);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});

io.on('error', function () {
    console.log("errr");
});


// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('view options', {layout: false});
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/testit', function (req, res) {
    res.send("it works!");
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});


// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

module.exports = app;
```

When I use 3000 rather than 80 for server.listen AND If I use node app.js rather than npm start to run my app, I don't see any problem and everything works, but does socketio override Express.js's settings that way?

I didn't touch bin/www file at all. It's right below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('future:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);



/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

Comment: The procedure here on StackOverflow if you're providing an answer to your own question is that you post an answer to your own question.  You leave the question as the question (without the answer).  Then, you post an answer that has the answer you found.  After a period of time, you can even accept your own answer to show the community that it worked for you.  This place is different than online forums that edit their question to show they have a solution.

Comment: You are correct. I added an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Create a file called io.js in your home directory (It was my choice to do so, you can place it somewhere else, though)

io.js

```
var io = require('socket.io')(); // yes, no server arg here; it's not required
// attach stuff to io
module.exports = io;
```

2. Open bin/www

Define your io variable after `var app = require('../app');`

`var io = require('../io');`

Place `io.attach(server);` just after `server.listen(port)`

3. Open app.js

Define your io variable and `io.on` parts just after `var app = express();`

```
var io = require('./io');

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('news', {hello: 'world'});
    socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});

io.on('error', function () {
    console.log("errr");
});
```

And finally, our view. Don't worry about the existence of socket.io.js, it's there. You don't have to download it manually or include some external file other than that.

```
html
    head
        title Socket.io
        script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")
    body
        script(src="javascripts/ol.js")
```

ol.js (test)

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', {
        my: 'data'
    });
});
```